# Android: How to Make For Loop Continue Loop After AsyncTask is finish (onPostExecute)

Tags: android, for-loop, android-asynctask

I have a value more than 1, so I planned to make a for loop to execute for each value. The problem is the for loop is looping/continue even the AsyncTask is not finish yet.

**AsyncTask Class**

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> {

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
       .........
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       .........
   }
}
```

**Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       Server  myServer = new Server();
       myServer.execute(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Asynctask is asynchronous... The loop will not wait

Answer (score 1):

As @cricket_007 commented, the loop won't wait as `AsyncTask` is asynchronous and hence the loop continues without waiting for the `AsyncTask` to finish. So as I've understood your purpose, you need to do something like this.

You need define an interface like this.

```
public interface ResponseListener {
    void responseReceiver();
}
```

Now modify your `AsyncTask` like this

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, Void> {

   public ResponseListener responseListener;

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
       // .........
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // ......... Other code
       // Now here's the callback function to the main activity.
       responseListener.responseReceiver(); 
   }
}
```

Now from your activity you need to do something like this.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements HttpResponseListener {
    public int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        Server  myServer = new Server();
        myServer.responseListener = this;
        myServer.execute(i);
    }

    // Callback method implementation
    @Override
    public void responseReceiver() {
        // This is the callback function and it gets called when one AsyncTask finishes.
        // Increase the count here and keep track of how many times the AsyncTask has been executed.

        // Do something 
        count++; 

        // Now call the next AsyncTask again if the count haven't reach 10 already
        if(count <= 10) {
            Server  myServer = new Server();
            myServer.responseListener = this;
            myServer.execute(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a bit of a long shot, but does the job I suppose.

```
static Boolean ASYNC_TASK_FINISHED;    
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    ASYNC_TASK_FINISHED = false;
    Server  myServer = new Server();
    myServer.execute(i);

    while(!ASYNC_TASK_FINISHED){ }
}
```

Then in your `AsyncTask`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   ...

   ASYNC_TASK_FINISHED = true;
}
```

You should make the `ASYNC_TASK_FINISHED` variable a global singleton one thats accessible by both `Activity` and `AsyncTask`.